# Http-Listener and download file

Tags: http, c#-4.0, webserver, httplistener

I have a Windows Service developed with C#. Now, I have to add a Http-Listener which should provide a small Html-Page. On this page, there should be a link, which can be clicked by the user for downloading a file. My Windows-Service should now provide the file. The Windows Service has the file but there is now way with directory from the client to the file. Does anybody know a library which I can use for this or other samples? - Thank you.

Best Regards, Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just use the normal System.IO classes to open a stream from the file and then push that stream into the HttpResponse (and set all the appropriate headers)?